# Finding values in a string via regex in php

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match

I am trying to get information out of a textarea that contains certain strings (e.g. [name]) and find each item encased in the square brackets using regex patterns (currently tried using preg_match, preg_split, preg_quote, preg_match_all). It seems that the problem is in my regex pattern that I am providing for it. 
My current regex:
`$menuItems = preg_match_all('/[^[][([^[].*)]/U', $_SESSION['emailBody'], $menuItems);`

I have tried many other patterns e.g.

`/(?[...]\w+): (?[...]\d+)/`

Any help that can be provided with this is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Sample input:
`[email] address [to] name [from] someone`

Message displayed on var_dump of the `$menuItems` variable:
array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }

EDIT 2:

Thank you to everyone for the help and support with this, I am pleased to say that it is all up and running perfectly!

Comment: The input comes from a textarea: <code> <textarea rows="10" name="emailBody" cols="100%"><?php if (isset($_SESSION['baseEmailBody'])) { echo $_SESSION['baseEmailBody']; } ?></textarea> </code>

Comment: Shouldn't `preg_match_all('/\[.*\]/U', $_SESSION['emailBody'], $menuItems);` work?

Comment: @Phylogenesis, that did something... message displayed to me on var_dump from that: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /apps/samSwift/email2.php on line 150

Comment: @Phylogenesis, that message appeared 3 times, offset 1 through to 3, one for each of the items I put into the textarea

Comment: Could it be something to do with the fact that I use a for loop to display the results from the array?

Comment: No, that will probably be because I didn't put a capture group into the regular expression. Try `/\[(.*)\]/U`. Also as stated in my comment below, do not overwrite `$menuItems` with the result of the function.

Comment: See [this example](http://ideone.com/yp5V9e).

Comment: So close now! It's only displaying 2 of the results from the array for some reason though, I entered: [email] address [to] name [from] someone as the input, the array contains: array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "[email]" [1]=> string(4) "[to]" [2]=> string(6) "[from]" } array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "email" [1]=> string(2) "to" [2]=> string(4) "from" }, but I only have [email] and [to] being displayed in my list...

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your loop. The fact the `var_dump()` now shows all the fields means you've got a problem later on in the code.

Comment: @Phylogenesis, thank you!!!! Could you do me a favor and add what you have said as an answer so that I can make it the accepted one? I want to do something to help you as you have done so much to help me :) (I'll have a look at my code and see if I can figure out the "not showing last value" issue, thank you again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comment stream above, you can simplify the regular expression as follows:

```
preg_match_all('/\[(.*)\]/U', $_SESSION['emailBody'], $menuItems);
```

One thing to note:

`preg_match_all()` fills the array in its 3rd parameter with the results of the matches. Your example line then overwrites this array with the result of `preg_match_all()` (an integer).

You should then be able to iterate over the results by using the following loop:

```
foreach ($menuItems[1] as $menuItem) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the square brackets and remove the dot:

```
$menuItems = preg_match_all('/[^[]\[([^[]*)\]/U', $_SESSION['emailBody'], $menuItems); 
//                         here __^    __^ ^
```

preg_match_all doesn't return a string. You have to add an array for the last parameter:

```
preg_match_all('/\[([^[\]]*)\]/U', $_SESSION['emailBody'], $matches);
```

The matches are in the array `$matches`

```
print_r($matches);
```

**Working example:**

```
$str = '[email] address [to] name [from] someone';
preg_match_all('/\[([^[\]]*)\]/U', $str, $matches); 
print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [email]
            [1] => [to]
            [2] => [from]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => email
            [1] => to
            [2] => from
        )

)
```

Comment: SUIS CHALIE I shall give this a go and let you know what happens. Thank you!

Comment: @swiftie821: How has't it work? Please update your question and give sample input string.

Comment: Your latest update doesn't make sense. `$menuItems` *is* the array to fill with the results. Albeit, it is then immediately overwritten with the integer result from `preg_match_all`.

Comment: I have added a sample input string and the message displayed when I var dump the $menuItems array

Comment: @Phylogenesis: preg_match_all returns the number of results or false if an error occurs. Have a look at the doc.

Comment: @JESUISCHARLIE, I did and I'm afraid it didn't work, Phylogenesis was able to help me figure this one out, thank you both :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. This regex will capture all items encased in brackets along with brackets as well.

If you don't want brackets in result change regex to `$regex = "/(?:\\[(\\w+)\\])/mi";`

```
$subject = "[email] address [to] name [from] someone";
$regex = "/(\\[\\w+\\])/mi";
$matches = array();
preg_match_all($regex, $subject, &$matches);
print_r($matches);
```